# Long exact sequence in Grothendieck group.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. I define the Grothendieck group $K(X)$ to be the free abelian group of locally free sheaves on $X$, modulo the relation $F = F' + F''$ whenever there is a short exact sequence $0 \to F' \to F \to F'' \to 0$.

Suppose I have 4 term exact sequence:
$$
0 \to F_1 \overset{f}{\to} F_2 \overset{g}{\to} F_3 \overset{h}{\to} F_4 \to 0
$$.
Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^4 (-1)^i F_i=0$? I am trying to understand the remark in Definition 10.5.1 in [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/main.pdf#page=207).

My thoughts were that you can break up the above exact sequence into kernels and images, write down the corresponding short exact sequences, and put together the equations to get the identity I want (essentially the calculation done [here](https://mathstrek.blog/2015/01/20/exact-sequences-and-the-grothendieck-group/)).

However the issue is that locally free sheaves do not form an abelian category, so I probably don't have kernels and images. I suppose one can enlarge $K(X)$ to be the free abelian group of coherent sheaves, but I am wondering if there is another way around this. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a surjection $F\to G$ of locally free sheaves, easy to check that the kernel is locally free. So, what you need is correct.